# Wordpress htacces, remove www, redirect to subfolder, clean url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Is there anyone who could help me with creating a decent htaccess file? I'm at this at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?outsideit.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://outsideit.net/main/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outsideit\.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://outsideit.net/main/index.php [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

My goal is that www is removed from the url, then the url is redirected to the subfolder main and then the /main/ is hidden, so that the url will always be http://outsideit.net
I can manage to achieve the above with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?outsideit.net$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ main/ [L]
```

But then the site is no longer working and gives an error "The page isn't redirecting properly". So I need to go to index.php somehow.

Thanks for any help with this.

Willem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress does this by itself without the need to modify your .htaccess as much as you are. Following the directions from here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

First thing first before you start this, go back to the clean .htaccess within the **root of your install** (not the root of the site). For your reference, here is a copy of the default .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress  
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]  
</IfModule>  
# END WordPress
```

Then follow the following directions:

> Create the new location for the core WordPress files to be stored (we will use /wordpress in our examples). (On linux, use mkdir wordpress from your www directory. You'll probably want to use "chown apache:apache" on the wordpress directory you created.)
>
> Go to the General panel.
>
> In the box for WordPress address (URL): change the address to the new location of your main WordPress core files. Example: http://example.com/wordpress
>
> In the box for Site address (URL): change the address to the root directory's URL. Example: http://example.com
>
> Click Save Changes. (Do not worry about the error message and do not try to see your blog at this point! You will probably get a message about file not found.)
>
> Move your WordPress core files to the new location (WordPress address).
>
> Copy (NOT MOVE!) the index.php and .htaccess files from the WordPress directory into the root directory of your site (Blog address). The .htaccess file is invisible, so you may have to set your FTP client to show hidden files. If you are not using pretty permalinks, then you may not have a .htaccess file. If you are running WordPress on a Windows (IIS) server and are using pretty permalinks, you'll have a web.config rather than a .htaccess file in your WordPress directory. For the index.php file the instructions remain the same, copy (don't move) the index.php file to your root directory. The web.config file, must be treated differently than the .htaccess file so you must MOVE (DON'T COPY) the web.config file to your root directory.
>
> Open your root directory's index.php file in a text editor
>
> Change the following and save the file. Change the line that says:
>   `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`
>   to the following, using your directory name for the WordPress core files:
>   `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`
>
> Login to the new location. It might now be http://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/
>
> Create the new location for the core WordPress files to be stored (we will use /wordpress in our examples). (On linux, use mkdir wordpress from your www directory. You'll probably want to use "chown apache:apache" on the wordpress directory you created.)

It will automatically redirect from www to non-www, without the need for additional modifications.

Comment: Thanks man! I've put this question on on multiple forums. Got all kind of overcomplicated suggestions. Yours is awesome. One small issue was that the home button was no longer working, but I changed it in the menu dashboard to the correct url.

Comment: Very glad I could help!